# Geo referencing RADARSAT-1 image

Tags: coordinates, geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, radar

I have lots of RADARSAT-1 file in GeoTiff format along with meta data where corner coordinates are available. Corner coordinates are for image portion(except the black portion). But, radar image has black shade on two sides, that make it difficult to georeferenced. How can I Geo reference all radar GeoTiff images. Can someone help me with code or some ideas?[image: RADARSAT-1 image, uploaded in JPEG format after resizing]

Answer (score 1):

since the square if this image is slightly tilted, I am quite sure that this GeoTIFF is already map projected/georeferenced. Check the properties (e.g. QGIS /ArcGIS) to see which map projection it is.

Actually, if you use gdal_warp on this Geotiff indicating your wanted output projection, it will probably read the existing map projection and reproject it into the one you want.
http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html
or use it within QGIS from the menue